# React router with nginx

Tags: reactjs, nginx, react-router

I have troubles to setup nginx with react router. I have tried all suggested solutions I found but none of them seems to cover my use case.

This is a structure on my filesystem served by nginx

```
/path/to/my/app
|- v1.0/index.html
`- v2.0/index.html
```

I have deployed several versions on my app, each is a standalone react app.

Then there's one more thing to complete the puzzle. My react app does not run on domain root URL (like `example.com/v1.0`) but rather on `example.com/my-app/v1.0`.

So I configured nginx like this

```
server {
  location ~ /my-app/([^/]+) { # capture version
    set $version $1; 
    root /path/to/my/app/$version  # directory where index.html is stored
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html
  }
}
```

Accessing `example.com/my-app/v1.0` works fine but if the path contains a route in react (`example.com/my-app/v1.0/users`), nginx returns `404` because it wants to serve a file `/path/to/my/app/v1.0/users` which obviously is not present.

Also it's worth to mention the my app does only work when accessed like `example.com/my-app/v1.0/` not like `example.com/my-app/v1.0/index.html`. The latter does not have any route configured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use `alias` with a *prefix* `location`, for example:

```
location /my-app/ {
    alias /path/to/my/app/;
    if (-e $request_filename) { 
        rewrite ^(/my-app/[^/]+) $1/index.html last; 
    }
}
```

The values of the `location` and `alias` directive should both end with `/` or neither end with `/`. Avoid `try_files` and `alias` due to [this issue](https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/97). See [this caution](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) on the use of `if`.

---

Another option is your approach, but replacing the `try_files` terms with the correct values. For example:

```
location ~ /my-app/(?<version>[^/]+)(?<suffix>/.*)?$ {
    root /path/to/my/app/$version;
    try_files $suffix $suffix/ /my-app/$version/index.html;
}
```